# colliderect() triggers unexpectedly

Tags: pygame, collision-detection, python-3.4, rect, surface

I am making a classic Snake game. I want to draw a green rectangle (`green_rect`), and whenever my snake touches it, that green rectangle moves to a new, random location. When I run `colliderect()` on the Worm's `surface`, it always returns `True` for some reason, though, even if the worm doesn't touch the rectangle.

So far I've tried:

```
width  = 640 
height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
green  = pygame.Surface((10,10)) #it's the rectangle
green.fill((0,255,0))
green_rect = pygame.Rect((100,100), green.get_size())

  # Our worm.
w = Worm(screen, width/2, height/2, 100)   # I have a class called Worm, described later...

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            w.key_event(event)   # direction control method in the Worm class

    if green_rect.colliderect(w.rect):  # w.rect is coming from Worm class: self.rect=self.surface.get_rect()
        # surface variable is 100 coming from: w = Worm(screen, width/2, height/2, 100) -- it describes the worm's length in segments / pixels.
        green_rect.x, green_rect.y = (random.randrange(420),random.randrange(300))


    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(green, green_rect)

    w.move() #function for movement in Worm class
    w.draw() #function for drawing the snake in Worm class
```

But this doesn't work, the green rectangle is moving uncontrollably, even if I don't touch it with the snake. `colliderect` must not be working since the x-y coordinates of the green rectangle are changing without the snake actually touching it. It should only change location when the snake touches the green rectangle.

> I didn't show all of my code, because its little long. If it necessary I can
>   write out Class Worm as well. Well *rect* method is not working on
>   lists, so I couldn't figure how to fix this problem.

**Edit**: Also I want to know how to resize the snake's segments, since my default size is a pixel (dot). I want it bigger so if it hits a big rectangle, even on a corner of the rectangle or along a side, rectangle will still move.

> **Edit-2:** Here is my `Worm` class:

```
class Worm():
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, length):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.length  = length
        self.dir_x   = 0
        self.dir_y   = -1
        self.body    = []
        self.crashed = False


    def key_event(self, event):
        """ Handle key events that affect the worm. """
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.dir_x = -1
            self.dir_y = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.dir_x = 1
            self.dir_y = 0


    def move(self):
        """ Move the worm. """
        self.x += self.dir_x
        self.y += self.dir_y

        if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
            self.crashed = True

        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))

        if len(self.body) > self.length:
            self.body.pop()


    def draw(self):
        for x, y in self.body:
            self.surface.set_at((int(x),int(y)), (255, 255, 255))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `Worm`s generate their `Rect`s exactly. Can we see the code for the `Worm` class? Or even just what `w.rect` returns during runtime?

There could be a few different problems, but what I suspect is that `w.rect` is actually filling the entire screen and collides wherever `green_rect` goes. It's a little hard to diagnose without knowing more about `Worm`, though.

We may not need all of `Worm`'s methods; `move()` and `init(..)` might do it.

Comment: @Augusta ok Im going to write whole code

Comment: Perfect, that tells me exactly what I need to know. Incidentally,  `import pygame, random, sys` are missing from your posted code, though I imagine you've got them in your original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what's going on here:
Your class `Worm` consists of an object that contains a list of xy-tuples, one for each pixel it occupies. The 'worm' creeps across the playfield, adding the next pixel in its path to that list and discarding excess pixel locations when it's reached its maximum length. But `Worm` never defines *its own rect* and `Worm.surface` is actually *the surface of the display area.*

The reason why your target `green_rect` hops around all the time is because `w.surface` refers to `screen`, not the Worm's own pixel area. `w.surface.get_rect()` is therefore returning a rectangle for the *entire display area*, as suspected. The green rectangle has nowhere to go that *doesn't* collide with that rect.

With that in mind, here's a solution for you:

```
  # in class Worm...
def __init__(self, surface, x, y, length):
    self.surface = surface
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.length = length
    self.dir_x = 0
    self.dir_y = -1
    self.body = []
    self.crashed = False

    self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,1,1)  # the 1,1 in there is the size of each worm segment!
      # ^ Gives the 'head' of the worm a rect to collide into things with.

  #...

def move(self):
    """ Move the worm. """
    self.x += self.dir_x
    self.y += self.dir_y

    if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
        self.crashed = True

    self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))

    if len(self.body) > self.length:
        self.body.pop()

    self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y
      # ^ Add this line to move the worm's 'head' to the newest pixel.
```

Remember to `import pygame, random, sys` at the top of your code and throw in `pygame.display.flip()` (or `update`, if you have a list of updating rects) at the end and you should be set.

As it stands, your code for a worm that crashes into itself runs, but has no effect.

One more suggestion: you may want to rename `Worm.surface` to something like `Worm.display_surface`, since pygame has a thing called `Surface` as well, and it might make it a bit easier for others to understand if the two were more clearly defined.

---

If you're looking for a more sophisticated worm consisting of a `list` of `Rect`s, that's also possible. Just replace the xy-tuples in the `Worm.body` list with `rect`s and replace `if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:` with `if self.rect.collidelist(self.body) != -1:` and it ought to work the same way. (`collidelist(<list of Rects>)` returns the index of the first colliding rect in that list, or -1 if there are none.)

Just make sure you also change the `self.rect` in `class Worm` so that it's more like

```
`self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y, segment_width, segment_height)`
```

...and adjust `self.dir_x` and `self.dir_y` so that they're equal to +/- `segment_width` and `segment_height`, respectively. You'll need to `fill` each segment or use `pygame.draw.rects` instead of using `set_at` in `Worm.draw()`, as well.

---

**UPDATE: Variable-size worm segments**

Here's some code that uses `Rect`s for the worm's body instead of xy-tuples. I have it set up so that the worm will define the size of each segment during initialization, then move forward in steps of that size (depending the axis of travel). Be aware the worm moves very quickly, has nothing stopping it from escaping the play area, and is quite long at 100 units length!

Here's my solution, in any case-- First is the revised `class Worm` code. I've marked altered lines with comments, including the lines that are new as of the original answer.

```
class Worm(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # MODIFIED CONTENTS!
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, length, (seg_width, seg_height)): # REVISED
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.length = length
        self.dir_x = 0
        self.dir_y = -seg_width # REVISED
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,seg_width,seg_height) # NEW/REVISED
        self.segment = pygame.Rect(0,0,seg_width,seg_height) # NEW


    def key_event(self, event):
        """ Handle key events that affect the worm. """
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = -self.segment.height # REVISED
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = self.segment.height # REVISED
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.dir_x = -self.segment.width # REVISED
            self.dir_y = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.dir_x = self.segment.width # REVISED
            self.dir_y = 0


    def move(self):
        """ Move the worm. """
        self.x += self.dir_x
        self.y += self.dir_y

        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y # NEW/MOVED

        if self.rect.collidelist(self.body) != -1: # REVISED
            self.crashed = True
            print "CRASHED!"

        new_segment = self.segment.copy() # NEW
        self.body.insert(0, new_segment.move(self.x, self.y)) # REVISED

        if len(self.body) > self.length:
            self.body.pop()


    def draw(self): # REVISED
        for SEGMENT in self.body:   # REPLACEMENT
            self.surface.fill((255,255,255), SEGMENT) # REPLACEMENT
```

...you'll have to revise the arguments when you assign `w`, too, to include your desired worm segment dimensions. In this case, I've closen 4 pixels wide by 4 pixels tall.

```
w = Worm(screen, width/2, height/2, 100, (4,4)) # REVISED
```

That's what I'd do. Note that you can assign whatever segment size you like (as long as each dimension is an integer greater than zero), even using single-pixel or rectangular (which is, 'non-square') segments if you like.

Comment: @user4381572 I can go into more detail about the list of Worm segment rects, if you like, but I didn't want to drone on with it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I just consider to not going to use colliderect method. But I will check your answer as _answer_ besides, do you know how can I grow the worm? I trying to add x,y coords to _body_ list but its not working actually.. oh and I didnt know there is a method calling _collidelist_ ? I search on web for _collide_ methods and I just found about Sprites. Disappointed..

Comment: Using the method you've got there, just add to `w.length`, since each xy-tuple you have in `w.body` is one pixel in the worm's "body." The more tuples you have, the longer the worm appears. Add `w.length += 1` or whatever length you'd have the worm grow by to the `if green_rect.colliderect(w.rect):` block you have in your main loop; that should do it!

Comment: That is what I want, thanks :-)  I add more tuples to body and its growing

Comment: One more question, can I draw a bigger worm, not longer? For example my worm is building by dots now, I want it bigger so user can see it easily on screen. Thicker.

Comment: You sure can, but it'd be easier for you to do that using `Rect`s instead of `tuple`s in `w.body`. I'll tack it on to the end of my answer for you.

Comment: Well I have to change whole codes than, if Im going to add rects instead of tuples right? And where is the _topleft_ variable before _self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y_ this one? I cant colliderect with _w.topleft_

Comment: I've added the new code for `Rect` segments to the answer, in the way I thought to do it. The worm also moves unmanagably quickly; even moreso now-- Consider looking at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock for ways to control your framerate (and thus, the speed of the worm)! :D